# How to make JQuery + CSS Vertical Tabs

Tags: jquery, css

Having trouble with my tabs, the Jquery is not functioning as i expect it to.

Im trying to create verticle tabs to display different information, but my jquery is not functioning.

1. I am trying to hide all the divs except the first one.
2. Then when one of the tab lists is clicked the active class gets added to that and removed from the other.
3. finally hide all the divs and show the one which was clicked.

[Click for jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KHAN/HjYZ6/2/)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    tabContent();
})

function tabContent() {
    $('#tabsD div:not(:first)').hide(); 
    $('#tab-container li').click(function(event){
        var id = $(event.target).index();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(event.target).addClass('active');
        $('#tabsD div').hide().eq(id).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical)?

Comment: @simbabque regarding the link u sent, how can i change the style of the lists to match mine?

Comment: Try this, or just google `how to styel jquery tabs`. http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this -

```
var id = $(this).index('li');
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/HjYZ6/6/

Comment: When i try this in dreamweaver and using my browser it doesent actually work. As soon as i click on another tab the description box goes

Comment: @KHAN Yes i do recommend you to use an already tested plugin instead of creating your own

Comment: How can i modify the jquery UI to make it look like my own.

Comment: i will leave using ui tabs for now, from what i can make of google seems like a real mission, editing it. any ideas why when i click a diff tab after implementing it this into the rest of my page the desc areas hide. ;/ Working perfectly fine on jsfiddle tho

Comment: after i click away from tab1 and try to go back to it, its also hidden

Comment: @KHAN.. Can you show your full code on somewhere like pastebin.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30650/discussion-between-khan-and-pxl)

Comment: Join discussion http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30650/discussion-between-khan-and-pxl

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel:

Look for Tabs on the left & Tabs on the right

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html